# Electron cannot compile for Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

While trying to compile for Windows i encounter this issue that i cannot find a solution.

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0PAT.png)

```
  ⨯ remove C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\XXXXX\XXXXX\dist\win-unpacked\chrome_100_percent.pak: Access is denied.
github.com/develar/go-fs-util.EnsureEmptyDir
        C:/Users/develar/go/pkg/mod/github.com/develar/go-fs-util@v0.0.0-20190620175131-69a2d4542206/fs.go:98
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.UnpackElectron.func1.1
        C:/Users/develar/Desktop/app-builder/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronUnpack.go:38
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/util.MapAsyncConcurrency.func2
        C:/Users/develar/Desktop/app-builder/app-builder/pkg/util/async.go:68
runtime.goexit
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
  ⨯ C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\XXXXX\XXXXX\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  stackTrace=
```

I try to manually add the binaries from `https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-download` but still cannot get the exe ready. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you could exclude the folder from your anti-virus softwares because they sometimes get control of files in an unwanted way.

Or sometimes a restart solves the problem.